# Compare and add property to array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have two arrays of objects (`Obj1` and `Obj2`).

The difference is that `Obj2` objects have an extra property called **fn**. I want to compare both arrays and if an object in `Obj1` has **fn** in `Obj2` for the same `datakey` then want to add `fn` in Obj1 also (the `datakey` is unique).

I don't want to change the order of `Obj1` array and I don't want to remove any extra object from `Obj1`.

I tried the following but, it doesn't seem to work or I am doing the wrong way.

```js
let Obj1 = [
        {
          "dataKey": "aaa",
          "title": "Lorem ipsum",  
          "description": "Dolor sit",
          "flag": true
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "ccc",
          "title": "dsff fsfsfs",  
          "description": "dsd ds ds ds",
          "flag": false
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "bbb",
          "title": "Duis aute irure",  
          "description": "eu fugiat nulla pariatur",
          "flag": false
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "ddd",
          "title": "Lorem ipsum dsds",  
          "description": "Dolor sit dsdsds",
          "flag": true
        },
      ];

let Obj2 = [
        {
          "dataKey": "aaa",
          "title": "Lorem ipsum",  
          "description": "Dolor sit",
          "flag": true,
          "fn": function() {
            console.log('hi');
          }
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "bbb",
          "title": "Duis aute irure",  
          "description": "eu fugiat nulla pariatur",
          "flag": true
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "ccc",
          "title": "dsff fsfsfs",  
          "description": "dsd ds ds ds",
          "flag": true,
          "fn": function() {
            console.log('hi');
            return 'abcd';
          }
        },
      ];
      
  Obj1.forEach(function(item){
    Obj2.forEach(function(newitem) {
      if(item.dataKey === newitem.dataKey && newitem.fn) {
        item["fn"] = newitem.fn;
      }
    })
})

console.log(Obj1);
```

**Expected Output:**

```
let Obj1 = [
        {
          "dataKey": "aaa",
          "title": "Lorem ipsum",  
          "description": "Dolor sit",
          "flag": true,
          "fn": function() {
            console.log('hi');
          }
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "ccc",
          "title": "dsff fsfsfs",  
          "description": "dsd ds ds ds",
          "flag": false,
          "fn": function() {
            console.log('hi');
            return 'abcd';
          }
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "bbb",
          "title": "Duis aute irure",  
          "description": "eu fugiat nulla pariatur",
          "flag": false
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "ddd",
          "title": "Lorem ipsum dsds",  
          "description": "Dolor sit dsdsds",
          "flag": true
        },
      ];
```

Comment: To make yours work as is just replace the references to `Obj1` and `Obj2` in your `forEach()` loops (ie:  `if (Obj1.dataKey === Obj2.dataKey && Obj2.fn) {...` ) with `item` and `newitem`. And close your function calls properly

Comment: added a missing `)` to your snippet so that it would run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate `Obj2` and use `Array.find()` to find the corresponding value on `Obj1`

```js
let Obj1 = [
        {
          "dataKey": "aaa",
          "title": "Lorem ipsum",  
          "description": "Dolor sit",
          "flag": true
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "ccc",
          "title": "dsff fsfsfs",  
          "description": "dsd ds ds ds",
          "flag": false
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "bbb",
          "title": "Duis aute irure",  
          "description": "eu fugiat nulla pariatur",
          "flag": false
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "ddd",
          "title": "Lorem ipsum dsds",  
          "description": "Dolor sit dsdsds",
          "flag": true
        },
      ];

let Obj2 = [
        {
          "dataKey": "aaa",
          "title": "Lorem ipsum",  
          "description": "Dolor sit",
          "flag": true,
          "fn": function() {
            console.log('hi');
          }
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "bbb",
          "title": "Duis aute irure",  
          "description": "eu fugiat nulla pariatur",
          "flag": true
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "ccc",
          "title": "dsff fsfsfs",  
          "description": "dsd ds ds ds",
          "flag": true,
          "fn": function() {
            console.log('hi');
            return 'abcd';
          }
        },
      ];
      
Obj2.forEach(function(newitem) {
  const obj = Obj1.find(item => item.dataKey === newitem.dataKey);
  if (newitem.fn)
    obj.fn = newitem.fn;
})

console.log(Obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like below for this.

```
const obj1WithFn = Obj1.map(item => {
    const objFromOtherArray = Obj2.find(({dataKey}) => dataKey === item.dataKey);
    if(objFromOtherArray && objFromOtherArray.fn) {
        item.fn = objFromOtherArray.fn;
    }
    return item;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let Obj1 = [
        {
          "dataKey": "aaa",
          "title": "Lorem ipsum",  
          "description": "Dolor sit",
          "flag": true
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "ccc",
          "title": "dsff fsfsfs",  
          "description": "dsd ds ds ds",
          "flag": false
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "bbb",
          "title": "Duis aute irure",  
          "description": "eu fugiat nulla pariatur",
          "flag": false
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "ddd",
          "title": "Lorem ipsum dsds",  
          "description": "Dolor sit dsdsds",
          "flag": true
        },
      ];

let Obj2 = [
        {
          "dataKey": "aaa",
          "title": "Lorem ipsum",  
          "description": "Dolor sit",
          "flag": true,
          "fn": function() {
            console.log('hi');
          }
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "bbb",
          "title": "Duis aute irure",  
          "description": "eu fugiat nulla pariatur",
          "flag": true
        },
        {
          "dataKey": "ccc",
          "title": "dsff fsfsfs",  
          "description": "dsd ds ds ds",
          "flag": true,
          "fn": function() {
            console.log('hi');
            return 'abcd';
          }
        },
      ];
Obj2.forEach((val, key) => {
    Obj1.find((search) => {if(search.dataKey === val.dataKey && val.fn){
        search.fn = val.fn
    }});
    
})
console.log(Obj1)
```